# Upgrade database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 — and rebuild full-text indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I upgraded from Sql Server 2005 to Sql Server 2008. I backed up the data in SQL Server 2005, and then I restored in SQL Server 2008. Next, I found the catalog under "Storage->Full Text Catalogs", and I right-clicked on it, and am trying to rebuild the Full-Text Catalog. The database is only 600mb. However, it keeps running for hours, and never semes to finish.

Comment: I remember Jeff Atwood talking about the full-text catalogs when they upgraded SO from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008.  Check it out here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/

Comment: Are there any errors in your Windows event logs or SQL Server log?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SQL Server 2008 has lousy Full-Text search because it is more tightly integrated into the database. There are some workarounds, but it isn't that great.

Answer (score 0):

It can take a long time to complete, I'd look at the FTLOGs (.log files) for the catalogs - if they are big I'd say it is having a problem indexing your documents. Is this RTM 2008?

Things you can try.

- Drop the indexes and create from
  scratch, dont use the interface - run
  this in a script.
- Check the Logs for possible
  errors.
- Ensure the Fulltext daemon    is
  running and indexing your
  documents , an issue with a CTP meant
  the daemon stopped.